# Heroku - Flask - Bcrypt error

Tags: python, flask

I am attempting to deploy a flask app on Heroku and it always errors at the same place. GCC fails to install and compile the Bcrypt module so I removed it from my requirements.txt (it is not used in the app). When I view the requrements.txt file, there is no mention of Bcrypt but when I push to heroku, it still tries to install it. I have committed the most recent version of requirements.txt to Git. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: We'll be able to help you better if you edit this to include the actual error.

Comment: distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

       ----------------------------------------
       Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-u25222/bcrypt

Comment: can you share setup.py code and requirements.txt file please ?

Comment: I've got the same error.  [requirements.txt](http://pastebin.com/kzBgdD5F)

Comment: Same error. I tried adding z3c.bcrypt python-bcrypt py-bcrypt-w32 and nothing changed.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve this by using this custom heroku build pack:

```
heroku config:add BUILDPACK_URL=git://github.com/mfenniak/heroku-buildpack-python-libffi.git
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get around it kind of, by successfully installing the following: "Successfully installed z3c.bcrypt python-bcrypt py-bcrypt-w32".  Installing one of these (likely the second one) is what probably included the main bcrypt library that I guess needed to be compiled? I not 100% sure...  I noticed this post is from July, I was able to download those libraries all using PIP.

Answer (score 0):

Add `cffi` or `cryptography` in `requirements.txt` .That solved the problem in my case.